# Building atom text editor from visual studio 2015

Tags: build, coffeescript, atom-editor

I have been attempting to contribute to the atom text editor from the source code posted on [github](https://github.com/atom/atom). I am in the process of building the application from the source code.

Here is some quick system information.

**Operating System:**
Windows 10(x64)

**Result of command:**
apm -v

```
apm  1.16.1
npm  3.10.5
node 6.9.5 x64
python 2.7.13
git 2.11.0.windows.3
visual studio 2015
```

I have ran the commands given by the atom [documentation (windows build)](https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/master/docs/build-instructions/windows.md) and it has created an output file correctly.(commands are listed below)

```
cd C:\
git clone https://github.com/atom/atom.git
cd atom
script\build
```

I have opened the atom folder as a website in visual studio 2015. Which I think is correct, but I am not entirely sure. Below is an image of my solution explorer in visual studio 2015. For the project atom, and it is opened as a website as previously stated.

[image]

Now as I attempt to build this application in visual studio(it states build sucessful), but I am receiving the error HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden(visual studios opens a local host). I followed the methods of Microsoft support [website](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/942062/-http-error-403.14---forbidden-error-when-you-open-an-iis-7.0-webpage), but those solutions did not fix my error. I wanted to know if I should build the application as a website in visual studio. Could that be the cause of this error?

**Other information:**

Web.config contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <configuration>
 <system.web>
   <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
 </system.web>
 </configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was asked by me again on the atom discussion board [Link Here](https://discuss.atom.io/t/building-atom-text-editor-from-visual-studio-2015/42170/2). Here is others answer, all credits go to Wliu and Scholar for answering.

Use script\build. If Visual Studio has an embedded terminal than you can use that so that you don't have to leave the editor. Atom does have an embedded terminal.

out\ should be automatically cleared for you when running script\build: https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/071ee3a06076f67e7708f4fdeffe85ac0e9d89c6/script/lib/clean-output-directory.js1
If you are constantly making changes to Atom core and want to test your changes quickly, you can run Atom in developer mode, which is much faster than rebuilding: atom --dev.